# Boot / shutdown time charge in Azure IaaS

Tags: azure, cloud, boot, iaas

Anyone know if, when I create a new VM in Azure, the boot time is charged? when I'm shutting down, is it charged too?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/

It seems yes, you get charged until the point where the status flips to Stopped (Deallocated).

[image]